# Cannot find the Order Entry folder in $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/

Tags: oracle, schema

I have downloaded and installed the most recent version of Oracle 12c (12.2.0.1.0). As stated on the page  https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00005,   I expected to find  oe_main.sql  in the folder $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/order_entry.  There is no such folder as you can see in my screenshot. I've only got the human_resources one. Why? Where are the others? Could anyone send them to me via e-mail? I am mostly interested in OE and OC . I have found some scripts on github, but I had serious problems due to many errors.

All the best!

[image]

**UPDATE**

Trying to execute the code  perl -p -i.bak -e 's#**SUB__CWD**#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql */*.sql */*.dat  ,  I get the following errors:

```
Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "'s#__SUB__CWD__#'$(" (Missing operator before $(?)


Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$(pwd"Missing operator before pwd?)

String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ")'#g'" (Missing operator before '#g'? )

syntax error at -e line 1, near "'s#__SUB__CWD__#'$(" Execution of -e aborted due to compillation errors
```

Comment: all these error messages are form perl and have nothing to do with Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is 12.1 documentation. You have a 12.2 database.

[Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/comsc/installing-sample-schemas.html#GUID-1E645D09-F91F-4BA6-A286-57C5EC66321D)

> Starting with **Oracle Database 12c Release 2**, the latest version of the
>   sample schema scripts are available on GitHub at
>   https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas/releases/latest.
>
> During a complete installation of Oracle Database, **the HR schema can
>   be installed** either manually or automatically when creating a database
>   using the dbca option. **All the other sample schemas must be installed
>   manually via the scripts available on GitHub.**

You can download the scripts from the above github URL.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've got stuck trying to follow this instruction:

Comment: <p>```shell
perl -p -i.bak -e 's#__SUB__CWD__#'$(pwd)'#g' *.sql */*.sql */*.dat  </p>        in order to replace  the occurrences of __SUB__CWD__ with my working directory.   It doesn't work, it results in errors, but most likely I don't understand how to follow that instruction. Could you advice me?    Thank you.

Comment: The errors are displayed in the screenshot available at  https://imgur.com/a/i24kI .

Comment: @Andrei please add the error as text formatted as code (eavh line preceded by 4 blanks) to your question

Comment: Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "'s#__SUB__CWD__#'$(" (Missing operator before $(?)

Comment: Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$(pwd"Missing operator before pwd?)

Comment: String found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ")'#g'"    (Missing operator before '#g'? )

Comment: syntax error at  -e line 1, near "'s#__SUB__CWD__#'$("Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors

Comment: I have just posted the errors to the question also.